# array_push() fail when called via extended class

Tags: php

I am new in PHP OOP. I have found the following code in book.

```
class Emailer 
{   
        protected $sender;
        private $recipients;
        private $subject;
        private $body;
    function __construct($sender)
    {
        $this->sender = $sender;
        $this->recipients = array();
    }
public function addRecipients($recipient)
    {
        array_push($this->recipients, $recipient); //error shown>>>array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given
    }
    public function setSubject($subject)
    {
        $this->subject = $subject;
    }
    public function setBody($body)
    {
        $this->body = $body;
    }
    public function sendEmail()
    {
    foreach ($this->recipients as $recipient)
    {
        $result = mail($recipient, $this->subject, $this->body,
        "From: {$this->sender}\r\n");
        if ($result) echo "Mail successfully sent to {$recipient}<br/>";
    }
    }
    }

$mailer=new Emailer("dalkum@creation.com");
$mailer->addRecipients("popy@youre.com");
$mailer->setSubject("good subject");
$mailer->setBody("Test mail");

class ExtendedEmailer extends emailer
    {
    function __construct(){}
        public function setSender($sender)
        {
    $this->sender = $sender;
        }
    }

$xemailer = new ExtendedEmailer();
$xemailer->setSender("dalim@creation.com");
$xemailer->addRecipients("rabbi@rmail.net");
$xemailer->setSubject("Just a Test");
$xemailer->setBody("Hi there Dalim, How are you?");
$xemailer->sendEmail();
```

Code runs well for the object `$emailer` but when I extend to `ExtendedEmailer`  it produces the message

> "Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\session\index.php on line 52shows " for the object
>   $xemailer.

Can anybody help whether I have problem defining inheritance OR problem with object creation?

Comment: private $recipients=array(); make the $recipients variable an array.

Comment: The class constructor, if defined, always must call `parent::__constructor()` to let the parent class initialize its members.

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting constructor in child-class so `$this->recipients = array();` never gets done and the variable is just `null`. You can change declaration of $recipients to this `private $recipients = array();`, not overwriting constructor or call parent-constructor after custom-code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `$this->recipients` class member gets initialised in the constructor of the `Emailer` class, but you're never calling that constructor when you're creating an `ExtendedEmailer` so it never gets initialised. Very often, you want your child class's constructor to call your base class's constructor, for example in `ExtendedEmailer`'s constructor you might have:

```
function __construct(){
    parent::__construct(/* you need a sender here */);
}
```

But the problem in our case is we don't have a sender to construct it with. If that's how we want our classes to behave, as I suspect it is, we should do the same initialisation that our base class performs:

```
function __construct(){
    $this->recipients = array();
}
```